# Sage50 Canada SDK location

Tags: sdk, sage-erp, sage50

Does anyone know how to access the latest sage50 Canada version SDK?

With the UK version it is included in the application files but I cannot locate the equivalent with the Canadian version.

Answer (score 0):

This link has the sage 50 sdks for the canadian version.  The page you get when you google contains broken links.

https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=89239&sliceId=1&noCount=true&isLoadPublishedVer=&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_Article&stateId=24605&cmd=displayKC&dialogID=1016781&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl&openedFromSearchResults=true